# Button and status bar still purple after switching color theme

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I switched all the colors in the `Color.kt` compose file to the ones I want. The problem is that the button I implmented is still purple. As you can see, its only the button which does not get the new Theme colors, but the text input fields are dark grey as intended.

[image]

This is the code:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    nav: NavController
) {
    val viewModel: LoginViewModel = viewModel()

    HanniverReloadedTheme() {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
        ) {
            var usernameTextField by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            var passwordTextField by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp),
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
                )
                TextField(
                    value = usernameTextField,
                    onValueChange = { usernameTextField = it },
                    label = { Text(stringResource(id = R.string.login_page_label_username)) },

                    )
                TextField(
                    value = passwordTextField,
                    onValueChange = { passwordTextField = it },
                    label = { Text(stringResource(id = R.string.login_page_label_password)) },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
                    visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation()
                )
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp),
                    onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
                ) {
                    Text(stringResource(id = R.string.login_page_button_login))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also the Statusbar didnt change color and is still purple. So I tried to change the colors also in the `colors.xml` file and changed also the `themes.xml` so that it routes to the right color. It worked but I dont like the solution. Is there another approach for that or is this the way we do it so far?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using that theme in your composable?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti It works on the TextFields. As if you see the caret and the focused underline have DarkGrey as color which is from the theme.

Answer (score 0):

In the jetpack compose, colors are set in the `Theme.kt` file. So what you need to change is the `Primary color` in this file. By doing that, the specified color would be applied to all of your buttons. But if you want to change the color of a single button, you can override `ButtonDefaults`:

```
Button(
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        backgroundColor =...,
        contentColor =...,
        disabledBackgroundColor =...,
        disabledContentColor =...
    )
) {

}
```

Comment: The Theme.kt has the changes. It works on the `TextField`